# Chart with multiple dates (on X-axis) and one line per status

Tags: reporting-services, charts, timeserieschart

Using SSMS 2008 R2, I have a table with a list of sales orders. Each row has:

- ID
- date
- status

I am just interested in the ID and status:

```
ODate   OStatus
------  -------
4-01    1
4-01    1
4-01    4
4-01    4
4-01    1
4-02    1
4-02    2
4-02    2
4-02    1
4-03    1
4-03    1
4-03    1
4-03    1
4-03    1
4-03    3
4-03    4
4-03    1
4-03    3
4-03    1
4-03    1
4-03    1
```

I want a line chart with:

- One line for each status;
- X-axis showing dates;
- Y-axis measuring the total each day *in their respective category*: how many 1, 2, 3, and 4 for each day.

I've tried many combinations of `GROUP BY` and `COUNT` options in SQL that don't work. I know I need multiple series, but I get an error or simply the same sum results in a horizontal line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do all the grouping at the report level based on the raw data above:

[image]

Results based on your DataSet:

[image]

No formatting or anything has been applied, but the results look correct.